# Best way to visualize nodes and have text within fully visible (D3.js, Neo4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have created a network visualization with D3.js and Neo4j as the underlying database. I try to be concise in naming the nodes, but still, not all text is clearly visible (see image below). Do you have any suggestions on how I can visualize this with the text being fully visible?

I can imagine it can be:

- Automatic scaling of the nodes based on the largest line of text. I don't want all nodes having different sizes, because I want the emphasis to be on all the nodes.
- Maybe not use circles, but some other form

What are the best practices here?

[image: D3 visualization]

Comment: You can configure the size of the nodes in Neo4j Browser. Make them bigger and more text will be in them

Comment: I tried this, but this is not very constructive, since some text keeps disappearing. In Dutch language, we write words attached to each other, so sometimes very long words are formed. Such as: Gemeenschapsvorming. This word falls off, no matter what the size of the model. This has made me wondering wether there are other ways of visualization or smart ways to adjust the node size.